# Vertx Webclient does not call handler

Tags: paypal, webclient, vert.x

I try to call the PayPal API, this works but vertx does not call any handler.
For example I call the the api via vertx like this:

```
WebClient.create(this.getVertx(), options)
                    .get(this.environment.getPort(), this.environment.getHost(), "/v1/billing/subscriptions")
                    .setQueryParam("id", subscriptionID)
                    .bearerTokenAuthentication(accessToken.result())
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .ssl(true)
                    .timeout(1)
                    .send()
                    .onFailure(res -> {
                        System.out.println("This will not be called");
                    })
                    .onSuccess(res -> {
                        System.out.println("This will not be called");
                    })
                    .onComplete(res -> {
                        System.out.println("This will not be called");
                    });
```

The log show me like this:

```
|000002c0| 61 79 70 61 6c 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 73 65 72 76 69 63 |aypal.com/servic|
|000002d0| 65 73 2f 73 75 62 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 73 |es/subscriptions|
|000002e0| 20 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 75 72 69 2e 70 61 79 | https://uri.pay|
|000002f0| 70 61 6c 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 73 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 |pal.com/services|
|00000300| 2f 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 2f 77 65 |/applications/we|
|00000310| 62 68 6f 6f 6b 73 22 2c 22 61 63 63 65 73 73 5f |bhooks","access_|
|00000320| 74 6f 6b 65 6e 22 3a 22 41 32 31 41 41 4b 6d 39 |token":"A21777m9|
|00000330| 55 34 7a 6d 75 4d 46 50 61 4a 6e 4d 78 66 65 72 |U4zmuMFP6666xfer|
|00000340| 7a 71 4f 46 56 63 5f 70 32 48 5a 6a 38 58 72 50 |zqOFVc_p2HZj8XrP|
|00000350| 6c 6d 5a 76 4e 59 7a 67 70 33 55 5a 47 34 51 55 |lmZvNY666666G4QU|
|00000360| 4a 43 65 6a 6e 4a 49 30 52 62 61 32 5a 5f 53 41 |JCejghfhRba2Z_SA|
|00000370| 56 4d 30 2d 69 71 4e 54 5a 36 47 59 34 59 5f 54 |VM0-iqNTZ6GY4Y_T|
|00000380| 70 36 4a 39 7a 46 41 53 51 22 2c 22 74 6f 6b 65 |p6J9zFASQ","toke|
|00000390| 6e 5f 74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 42 65 61 72 65 72 22 |n_type":"Bearer"|
|000003a0| 2c 22 61 70 70 5f 69 64 22 3a 22 41 50 50 2d 38 |,"app_id":"APP-8|
|000003b0| 30 57 32 38 34 34 38 35 50 35 31 39 35 34 33 54 |0W284ggfdfg9543T|
|000003c0| 22 2c 22 65 78 70 69 72 65 73 5f 69 6e 22 3a 33 |","expires_in":3|
|000003d0| 31 36 30 39 2c 22 6e 6f 6e 63 65 22 3a 22 32 30 |1609,"nonce":"20|
|000003e0| 32 33 2d 30 33 2d 31 36 54 31 36 3a 30 32 3a 31 |23-03-16T16:02:1|
|000003f0| 34 5a 69 39 72 35 79 70 73 68 4e 70 65 38 4a 36 |4Zi9rfffffbpe8J6|
|00000400| 52 59 42 59 57 6b 65 39 44 33 71 31 70 6e 6b 71 |RYBYvvv9D3q1pnkq|
|00000410| 79 42 4b 49 4f 49 73 48 46 73 31 49 30 22 7d    |yBKIOIsHFs1I0"} |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2023.03.16 17:15:25.133 [DEBUG] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler: [id:  0x7dba3957, L:/192.168.178.22:64324 - R:api.sandbox.paypal.com/173.0.93.150:443] READ COMPLETE
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64313', transport: 'socket'
```

Just to check the API and the credential is working from Paypal side, I execute the Curl request:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-AGEG7AMDEFD \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAKujR2DggVYD0Feb4444K2S9L851WGdddxNffqsa0QxJ8xGZDxj8ASymp6W4_Mmr4176M9rV-jVJeHeMEx3BwPODBQ"
```

and it works, I receive 200 back.
So for my understanding the call was successfully, but web client from Vert.x doesn't work correctly, it doesn't show any reaction. Do anyone knows why vertx stopp working?

Comment: Did you try attaching an onSuccess handler?

Comment: yes sry, I add the onSuccess of course, but the effect is the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, to get the access token, I create a web client and this response called the handler to get the subscription status, so to web client a created two times (in the get access token method and in the get subscription method). First call to get the access token:

```
this.webClient
                .post(this.port, this.host, "/v1/oauth2/token")
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .putHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .authentication(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.clientID, this.clientSecret))
                .sendForm(multiMap)
                .andThen(response -> {
                    if (response.succeeded()) {
                        final JsonObject json = response.result().bodyAsJsonObject();
                        final long expiredIn = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + (long) json.getInteger("expires_in");
                        this.expires.set(expiredIn);
                        this.accessToken = json.getString("access_token");
                        callback.handle(Future.succeededFuture(this.accessToken));
                    } else {
                        callback.handle(Future.failedFuture(response.cause()));
                    }
                });
```

and the second call to get the subscription:

```
WebClient.create(this.getVertx(), options)
                .get(this.environment.getPort(), this.environment.getHost(), "/v1/billing/subscriptions")
                .setQueryParam("id", subscriptionID)
                .bearerTokenAuthentication(accessToken.result())
                .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .ssl(true)
                .timeout(1)
                .send()
                .onFailure(res -> {
                    System.out.println("This will not be called");
                })
                .onSuccess(res -> {
                    System.out.println("This will not be called");
                })
                .onComplete(res -> {
                    System.out.println("This will not be called");
                });
```

The solution is to just create one web client and the second call use the same web client instance. Sry when I read the question nobody can answer this, because it was not clear in my question.